# Best way to get properties from html and use as global variable in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

What is the best way to get properties from html and use as global variable in Angular 2+?

index.html

```
...
<script>
    window.properties = {
        'variable1': 'string 1',
        'variable2': 'string 2'
    };
</script>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Injectable()
class MyGlobalService {
  properties$:Subject = new BehaviorSubject();

  constructor() {
    this.properties.next(window.properties);
  }
}
```

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [MyGlobalService],
  ...
 })
 class AppModule()
```

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myGlobals:MyGlobalService) {
    myGlobals.properties$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }
}
```